# Connecting to more than one database with pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

My app is connected to a main server PostgreSQL for 99% queries but sometimes I need to lookup some data on a different database located on a different server (there are ~300 potential databases for these lookups).

So I need to temporarily connect to a different server/db, get the query results and close that connection. The only "viable" solution I currently see is to use a different library for this sole purpose.

I have seen a milestone for version 0.2.0 of pg-promise that permits `multi-connector` though I can not find any reference to this anywhere. Maybe it's called differently now? Any pointers/examples?